# IOS : I am using PDColoredProgressView for my progressive view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiprogressview

This is my code , i have added NStimer

```
 PDColoredProgressView *progressVIew =[[PDColoredProgressView alloc] initWithProgressViewStyle:UIProgressViewStyleDefault];
    [progressVIew setFrame:CGRectMake(50, 50, 200, 25)];
    [progressVIew setProgress:0.1 animated:YES];
   [ progressVIew setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    [self.view addSubview:progressVIew];




 - (IBAction)startCount:(id)sender
    {
        _progressVaalue = 0.0f
        self.myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(updateUI:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    }

    - (void)updateUI:(NSTimer *)timer
    {
           int count =0; count++;
           if (count <= 1)
       {
           _progressVaalue = _progressVaalue + 0.1;
           progressVIew.progress = _progressVaalue;
                 }
```

I am getting like this
This is my code, the progressive view not Showing 
[image]